# modules, drupal, civicrm updates

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, ckeditor, upgrade

I have multiple updates to perform
modules, civicrm and drupal.
In what order should I do these updates?
Views (for Drupal 7) (Security update)  7.x-3.20    to 7.x-3.24
CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor (Security update)    to 7.x-1.18 7.x-1.19
Drupal core (Security update)   7.63    7.72
CiviCRM 5.9.1 to 5.28.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first upgrade all drupal core and modules, have the site working and than upgrade Civi.

I would prioritise security ones first.

Comment: Should I upgrade Civi  in steps or just go straight to the latest version?

Comment: where are the old versions?

Comment: I would upgrade directly from 5.9.x to 5.28.3